# Unable to get proper uninterrupted internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am unable to get proper internet connection on my HP laptop. Its product number is 15-ac044tu. My laptop connects to my wifi router but won't get internet packets.  I will get the internet packets for some duration of 10 min or so and  suddenly I will not recive the internet packets for some dutation of 5 min. This cycle keeps on repeating, but it still it shows connected.

If I disconnect and reconnect I get the internet packets but not for very long. There is no problem with my wifi network or the ISP; all works fine on my mobile (which is connected to my wifi router) when this problem occurs on my PC. I have tried many solutions for this problem and many linux distros, but still have the same issue.

The following is my ping data:-

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
455 packets transmitted, 103 received, 77% packet loss, time 462163ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.059/70.693/531.069/93.588 ms
```

network-manager logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93as1q1NvuPSWlWcE1qb2w0WHc/view

Comment: Please review [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and [edit] your answer to include more details

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version, what is the wireless adapter?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 and BCM43142 802.11b/g/n